# Error al ingresar datos : TypeError: Cannot read property '4' of undefined

Tags: google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo

Al ejecutrar la función que invoca a la otra (`registrarOcupacion()` invoca a `procesarHojaOcup(hojaOrigen)`) y al procesar la macro me tira un error en la línea 100:

`matriz.push(aux.concat(semana,fechas[semana][4],fechas[semana][5],fechas[semana][6],datos[f][c] * 8,'','Ocupación'))`

El error es el siguiente:

> TypeError: Cannot read property '4' of undefined (línea 100, archivo "macroPlaneacion")Cerrar

Antes me funcionaba bien pero no sé por qué no me sirve ya, si se necesitan más detalles me comentan por favor, aún sigo aprendiendo a hacer preguntas en este sitio

**CÓDIGO**

```
function registrarOcupacion(){
  let archivoDestino = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  let hojaDestino = archivoDestino.getSheetByName('BD');
  var hojaOrigen = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  
  let archivoOrigen = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/187Mvtj_ExSQ9nil_NbwNmSTcjZ_X1i6GfXcOMMMnn7Y/edit#gid=858356230');
  
  //crear fechas
  fechas = archivoDestino.getSheetByName('Calendario').getDataRange().getValues()
  personas = archivoDestino.getSheetByName('Personas').getDataRange().getValues()
  
  let hojasArchivoOrigen = archivoOrigen.getSheets()
  for(let h of hojasArchivoOrigen){
    let nombre = h.getName()
    if(nombre.substr(0,1) != '_'){
      let hojaOrigen = h
      procesarHojaOcup(hojaOrigen)
    }
  }
  
  let rangoDestino = hojaDestino.getRange(2, 1, matriz.length, matriz[0].length)
  rangoDestino.setValues(matriz)
  Browser.msgBox('Fin del proceso')
}


function procesarHojaOcup(hojaOrigen) {
  
  let datos = hojaOrigen.getDataRange().getValues()
  for(let f = 3, l = datos.length; f < l; f++){
    if(datos[f][0] != '' && datos[f][0] != 'Totales'){
      let persona = personas.filter(p => p[0] == datos[f][0])
      let aux = [
        hojaOrigen.getName()
      ]
      aux = aux.concat(persona[0])
      aux = aux.concat(
        datos[f][1],
        datos[f][2],
        datos[f][3]
      )
      for(let c = 21; c <= 57; c++){
        if(datos[f][c] !=''){
          let semana = datos[2][c]
          matriz.push(aux.concat(semana,fechas[semana][4],fechas[semana][5],fechas[semana][6],datos[f][c] * 8,'','Ocupación'))
        }
      }
    }
  }
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast('', hojaOrigen.getName())
}
```

Error en el registro:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Vas bien, has incluído el error textual y has sido claro con respecto a la línea de código a la que se refiere. Te sugiero que en lugar de poner todo el código incluyas un [mcve] (además de código más corto deberías incluir datos de entrada y así como el resultado esperado.

Comment: Deberías mandar al navegador valores de depuración de `console.log(semana, fechas[semana])` y, además, nos vendría bien que compartieras el contenido de **`fechas`** para ver si tiene el índice que solicitas.

Comment: ¿Qué acción dispara la ejecución del código que estás depurando? Por ahora no sale nada en la consola de depuración de javascript. Además, en uno de los botones verdes me aparece un mensaje de error: "**Exception: No tienes permiso para acceder al documento solicitado**". Además, he agregado un `console.log(semana);` y no veo el resultado porque no llega a esa línea la ejecución.

Comment: Me vuelve a dar error de acceso. He clonado tus documentos para no modificar tu código, pero sigue intentando ejecutar tus secuencias de instrucciones :( he de dejarte, espero que puedan ayudarte. PD: Procura hacer copia de tus documentos durante el desarrollo, no trabajes con los originales ni compartas los originales aquí. Cualquiera podría acceder a ellos.

Comment: He compartido las copias, pero estaban apuntando al documento original que es Formato T.I. ¿has hecho algún cambio a la macro?

Comment: Ya cambié a los documentos que apunta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esta solución la obtuve del foro StackOverflow en inglés, link a la pregunta: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62313084/typeerror-cannot-read-property-4-of-undefined-at-line-100

Reemplazando

```
if(datos[f][c] !=''){
```

por

```
if(datos[f][c] !='' && datos[f][c]){
```

sirvió para resolver el problema

Comment: Está muy bien que compartas que has encontrado una solución y el enlace a la misma, pero si lo vas a publicar como respuesta deberías incluir las partes más relevantes (especialmente si la fuente está en un idioma diferente al español)

Comment: Listo, ya lo agrego. Gracias

Answer (score 1):

El error quiere decir que `fechas[semana]` es está devolviendo `undefined`. Justo en la línea previa tienes

```
let semana = datos[2][c]
```

Es probable que `datos[2][c]` está devolviendo un valor mayor al índice del último elemento de `fechas`.

Te sugiero aprender a utilizar el depurador de código del editor de Google Apps Script así como el uso de `console.log` / `console.info`

Comment: Ya hice la depuración y me trae las 53 semanas, no veo un desborde de datos

Comment: Igualmente manda al navegador el valor con un `console.log(semana, fechas[semana])` y, además, nos vendría bien que compartieras el contenido de `fechas[semana]` para ver si tiene el índice que solicitas.

Comment: ¿Y también les sería de ayuda una copia de las dos sheets?

Comment: He estado tentado de solicitarte acceso para comprobar el código. Si te ofreces a darnos acceso te mando solicitud. PD: Con acceso de solo lectura es suficiente (si nos deja hacer una copia podremos hacer pruebas en nuestra copia sin alterarte tu documento :)

Comment: Tengo la copia con información no sensible, ya les doy los links: Link de la información a procesar: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1naHm-28Hahv-P0_-q8Aobz8RDQkcky8VrWQY5cWPbY8/edit?usp=sharing. Link de la macro: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xLDjqwoqhg9BKQ6Rib2eugAc0dk8af-OEPFjtMy8AvI/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Al parecer están apuntando la macro al original, ya lo corregí

Comment: Link a la que debe apuntar la hoja: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1naHm-28Hahv-P0_-q8Aobz8RDQkcky8VrWQY5cWPbY8/edit?usp=sharing. Ya lo acutalicé